Historic drama about a woman's affair with an Asian man - 2000/2010
I remember seeing a movie with my mother at the cinema, probably between 2000 and 2010. It was a long movie, kind of classic, drama romance. A love story between a white woman and an Asian man, I would say it takes place in a colonial environment. Maybe the Asian man was some kind of a rich man or prince. It must have been kind of soft erotic sometimes, and there were a lot of water and boats involved. I have been looking for films taking place in Vietnam/Indochine but I can't find this one. I would love your help on this! I remember she really loved it and I would like to find it before Christmas =) 

Possibly The Lover, but it's from 1992. Do you remember what they looked like, perhaps?

Sounds like The Lover.  I have seen it, and I couldn't imagine watching it with my mom.  :)


Set in 1920s colonial Indochina, a pretty, virginal French teenager (Jane March) meets a handsome Chinese playboy (Tony Leung Ka Fai) from a respectable family. Going against the conventions of their respective societies, the lustful pair begin a torrid affair in a seedy Saigon neighborhood. Their strong attraction towards one another is only intensified by the illicit nature of their rendezvous. Given such circumstances, can their relationship last?

Not a lot of boats/water, but a scenes do feature one or the other:





I remember at least one more scene featuring water, but I would get in trouble if I posted a picture of it here. :)

Could this be the movie Anna and the King from 1999?
It plays in Siam around 1860 and is the love story between a british teacher and the king of siam. You have the rich asian here (king),148 minutes(long movie), it is drama/romance and has a colonial like environment. But i am not sure about the soft erotic and the water and boats...
